# Add a sliding button panel to a DataGrid row/cell

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I want to add an animation to a DataGrid that I have.  Basically, when a user selects a row, from the right (the last cell), two buttons will slide into view.  When the mouse leaves the row, the buttons slide back.

Right now I have it so the buttons appear in the RowDetailsTemplate (and have it so the details disappear when the mouse leaves the row).  This is functional, but was hoping to get a little fancier.  Here's my current implementation:

```
<!-- Show Ack and Rem buttons in row details-->
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <TabPanel>
         <Button Name="AcknowledgeButton" Content="Acknowledge" Click="Ack_Notification" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Background="{StaticResource AckBrushStyle}" Visibility="{Binding Path=showAcknowledged, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}" Cursor="Hand"/>
         <Button Name="RemoveButton" Content="Remove" Click="Rem_Notification" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Background="{StaticResource RemBrushStyle}"/>
     </TabPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

<!--Hide the Row details--> 
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
  <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <EventSetter Event="MouseLeave" Handler="Hide_Details"/>
  </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Instead, I want to do something more like:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DataGridRow.MouseDown">
      <BeginStoryBoard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="AckButton"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Width)"
            To="100" Duration="0:0:3"/>

          <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="RemButton"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Width)"
            To="100" Duration="0:0:3"/>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
   </EventTrigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
```

I think where I'm failing is that I want to have these slide into the last cell (which is larger than it needs to be based on the data, so there is room for this).

Should I be looking at the DataGridTemplateColumn to create my own custom column that accommodate text on the left horizontal alignment and one or two buttons on the right alignment?  Or should I create two extra columns, one for each button?

The only issue I see with the column approach is that I wouldn't want those columns normally displayed, and when the buttons do show, I want to hide the fact that they're separate columns.

The other approach I was looking into was actually drawing the buttons as rectangles, essentially having an overlay on top of the row, but I think that is a far more complicated approach.  But maybe not?

Thanks for any help.  Prefer being pointed to APIs that can help, I'm not looking for someone to write this code for me ;)

Comment: What have you done so far? Where is your sample markup where the Buttons are defined?

Comment: Updated with code and what I'm thinking of doing.  Looking for more of a "what's the best approach" suggestion than actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I just found this example for a DataGridTemplateColumn:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="My Item">
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Image Source="{Binding MyImage}" />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}" />
      </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Unfortunately work's development environment is down right now so I can't test it out, but looks like I could create a panel with the buttons, start their size at 0 width and then animate the width on click, then when the mouse leaves, animate them back to width 0.